# how do you allow editing after entering a password for anonymous users?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a google Spreadsheet, and I want everyone with the link to be able to view it, but only certain people to edit it. Some people who should be able to edit it dont have a google account, so they will be seen as anonymous.
My idea was to make a script that asks the user for a password, if it is the right password I want to give them editing rights. I have no idea how to do that.
currently I have this code:

```
function onOpen(e){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  ui.createMenu('Password').addItem('enter password', 'password').addToUi()
}
function password(){
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  var password='123abc'
  var inp=ui.prompt('Enter Password')
  if(inp==password){
    ui.alert('correct Password')
    //somehow give user permissions
    Logger.log(up)
  }else{
    ui.alert('wrong Password')
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Triggers - both simple and installable [do not run if a file is opened in read-only  mode](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#restrictions)

Thus, a viewer will not see the menu and will not be prompted  to introduce his password

WORKAROUND:

**Create a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)**

Ask the user to introduce the password clientside, and if he got it right - run the serverside function to give user [permissions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addeditoremailaddress) with [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#index.html)

**Sample based on the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#detailed-documentation):**

*code.gs*

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
}

function giveAccess(emailAddress) {
  SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX").addEditor(emailAddress);
}
```

*Index.html*

```js
    <body>
        <label>Type in your email:</label>
        <input type="text" id="email"/><br/>
        <label>Type in the password:</label>
        <input type="text" id="password"/><br/>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()"/>
        <script>
            function myFunction() {
                var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
                if (password == "123abc") {
                    email = document.getElementById("email").value;
                    alert("You will receive edit access!");
                    google.script.run.giveAccess(email);
                } else {
                    alert("The password is wrong!");
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
```